# Grammar: Combine 慣れる and -くなる

Tags: grammar

I am stuck trying to explain that "I got accustomed". I would like to use the same grammar as in:

> 寒くなる

But with

> 慣れる

Could you point me to the right direction and also share other patterns to express the fact to get accustomed/used to something over time?

Comment: 慣れる itself is a kind of くなる

Comment: I see. So how about we think about another verb in -た form + -くなる?

Comment: It depends. I think in this case, you can just say 慣れた, 慣れてきた, 慣れている, etc. There is a more general pattern ～ようになる to put an arbitrary clause into ～なる.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot combine 「[慣]{な}れる」 with 「なる」.

「[寒]{さむ}くなる」 is fine because 「寒い/寒く」 is an adjective.  「慣れる」 is a verb.

To express "to get accustomed to", you can say:

> 「慣れてくる」 and 「慣れていく」.

No other forms could express the "get" part of "to get accustomed to" nearly as closely as these two.

> 「[大学生活]{だいがくせいかつ}にも慣れてきました。」 = "I am getting used to my college life."
>
> 「まだ大学生活には慣れていませんが、これから少しずつ慣れていくと思います。」 = "I am not used to college life yet, but I think I will get used to it little by little from now on."

Notice neither いく nor くる is used in the first part of my second example sentence because it says "I am not used to".